# Keeping default outlook format when creating a new html e-mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a simple script to create a html message, and I would like to keep as much as possible of the default values.

In my case when I create a new message using Home `->` New mail it would always create a mail with default font [Calibri 11'], format text Html, and also with a signature.

If I use the function `Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)` it creates the mail without issues.

However as soon as I declare an html body with `.HTMLBody` it will overwrite the format: font [Times New Roman 12'], and also without a signature.

Even more surprising: if I use the 'trick' found online to keep the signature (see code bellow) then the font would be then overwritten to [Calibri 10'] (one point bellow the default)

Any recommendation/explanation?

*Simple script to create an html mail (change of font + no signature) :*

```
Sub TestMessage1()
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objMsg
    .To = "test@domain"
    .Subject = "test Mail"
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Hello,<br><br>Could you please review this program<br><br>Regards,</p>"
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

*write html mail with a signature (different change of font):*

```
Sub TestMessage2()
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objMsg
    .To = "test@domain"
    .Subject = "test Mail"
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Hello,<br><br>Could you please review this program<br><br>Regards,</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the text or well-formatted HTML markup right after the `<body>` tag and before the closing `</body>` tag. In that case all format preferences will be preserved.

Comment: On the first script, using the `<body>` tag does not work. On the second however, using the `<body>` tag works, for instance `.HTMLBody = "<body><p>Hello,</p><\body>" & objMsg.HTMLBody` so +1 for the answer

Comment: Not exactly so... You need to insert the text or markup into the `<body> ... </body>` tags.

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't see what I am missing. If I write as simple as `.HTMLBody = "<body>Hello<\body>"` I have inserted my whole text (one word) into the  `<body> ... </body>` tags. Yet the text does not display properly. do you have eventually an example code that works for you?